# How to copy files from NFS share without using mount

Tags: files, mount, nfs, scp, shared-folders

I want to copy files from a server that has an NFS share to my machine without mounting it on my machine.

I want to put this in a script everyone else can use, and mounting requires root permissions so I prefer not to do that. Also the server in question seems to block `ssh` so any solutions like `scp` or `rsync` or `sftp` don't work either.

Is there any way to do this? Preferably one-lines like when using `scp` or `rsync`

Comment: You have an answer. You need to use `scp` or `rsync` after making sure that the client and the users have SSH access to server. If you want everyone to be able to use it, have the script prompt for a username that can be used to connect to the client. If the issue is that it requires sudo to mount, then someone with sudo can just put it in `/etc/fstab` which would mount it at boot and remove the need for a script.

Comment: did you try a simple `cp` with the files UNC path?

Comment: @NasirRiley I do not have control over this server, so I don't know if i can enable SSH or not. This script is shared through git to many people, so I don't have a simple way to change that file on everyone's machines

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I can't seem to get this to work. Do you mean that if my path is `\\server\share` i should do something like `cp \\server\share .` ? I can't manage to get it to work. In general only on my Windows machine can i even view these files without mounting, even through the browser it doesn't work for me on Linux

Comment: If the machine from which you are trying to access the files is running Linux, then you need to consult with whoever manages the NFS server so that they can add the machine as a client and/or give SSH access from the machine. Even better, after that's done, consult with the owner of the machine and have them add the NFS export from the NFS server to /etc/fstab so that it will mount at boot.

Comment: This has been wrestled with before, yet without answer.  https://superuser.com/questions/885662/what-should-i-use-to-access-nfs-from-console-without-mounting-it

Comment: A potential solution would be to build and use the `fuse-nfs` command.   Though I haven't tried it.  And the author cautions that even with it you'll probably need someone with root access to take some minimal action.  https://github.com/sahlberg/fuse-nfs

Comment: *" if my path is `\\server\share` i should do something like `cp \\server\share .` ?"* **--** You cannot copy "the share" so the command should be `cp //server/share/the-file .` Buit since you use backward slashes the question arises if that is really a *NFS* share oder a *Windows share* which uses the *SMB* protocoll...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I'm bad with slash directions and as I said i can't get it to work at all through Linux. I shall try your way and see if it works, but I think I've tried it in the past. I don't see how something like that can work without mounting really.

Comment: Looks like I'm right and you work with a SMB share. Try your luck with this: https://www.dark-hamster.com/operating-system/linux/samba/how-to-copy-file-from-linux-to-windows-using-samba-smbclient/